# How to check whether unordered_map contains a specific value?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

In Java, `containsValue()` function checks whether a hashmap contains a specific value. It looks for values, not for keys.

How to achieve that in c++?

Especially for `unordered_map`.

Comment: Here you can see all the functions, and you will find functions to check for containment. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map

Comment: There is no such thing in [unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map), you have to program it yourself (~3-4 lines of code).

Comment: `containsValue` looks for values not for keys, right? Better clarify that in the quesiton. Not every C++ programmer is familiar with Java

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin he's looking for values, not for keys, but anyway the link you provided is not really related to the question

Comment: java often takes a quite different approach than c++. In c++, when an operation cannot be done efficiently, chances are high that there is no standard method but you can implement it yourself when you need it. Java on the other hand tries to be fool proof, so it would provide you the method instead of assuming you can write it. maps are made to look up values based on keys efficiently, not to find values.

Comment: The unordered_map doesn't support it, but we can use `boost:bimap` as an alternative to achieve it.

Comment: If you need this, map (ordered or not) is probably a wrong data structure for you.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/count

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I think the more relevant distinction is that C++ has free functions, so that you don't need (at least) 4 copies of `map.containsValue(value)`, you just need one `contains_value(maplike, value)`

Comment: @Caleth `MapHelper.contains_value(map,...)`. Sorry, maybe my initial comment was too offtopic. Lets just agree that they are fundamentally different, and there are reasons why methods that exist in one do not exist in the other.

Comment: @Caleth in Java you could have `Algorithm.containsValue(mapLike)` as a static function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such method, but you can easily write it using [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and a lambda:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> m {{1, "bar"}, {2, "foo"}};
std::string needle = "foo";
auto found = std::find_if(m.begin(), m.end(), [&needle](const auto& p){return p->second == needle;});
if (found != m.end()) {
    // found->second is "foo"
} else {
    // not found
}
```

Comment: This may have performance issues, I would prefer to use `boost::bimap`

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin `boost::bimap` has performance issues itself. It's a huge thing, and I'm not sure if it would really improve anything for small maps. You can of course write your own answer, presenting how to do that with bimap, although I'm not sure if that's what OP wants (given they are using `std::unordered map` already).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen you wouldn't use `unordered_map` for a small number of elements, you would use a sorted vector.